# Custom Simulator for Deep Reinforcement Learning

Tags: lstm, reinforcement-learning, attention-mechanism

I am trying to develop a control method for a specific process in industry. I have a time-series of data for the process and want to develop a prediction model base on attention mechanism to estimate the output of the system.

After development of the prediction model, I want to design a controller based on Deep Reinforcement Learning to learn policies for process optimization. But I need a simulated environment to test and train my DRL algorithm on it.

How can I create a custom environment or simulator based on my attention mechanism prediction model for DRL? Can I implement it with the help of OpenAI Gym?

I will appreciate it if you help me.